# Can 'extern' be omitted when using global variables?

Tags: c, compilation, extern

Recently I found a strange thing about 'extern' in C

[image: valid, didn't get a compile error]

When I compile it using `gcc tmp.c tmp2.c -o tmp -Wall`, it turns out pretty well with no compile errors (nor warnings!). The output is `1`. But the following code won't pass the linkage process (the only difference is that I initialize `tmp` in the second file):

[image: This won't do]

It seems that the compiler regards any uninitialized variables as external variables?

Comment: Paste code into the question as text, not images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int x = value;` is a definition of `x`. Having two of them at file scope creates multiple definitions, resulting in a link error.

`int x;` at file scope is a tentative definition. Per the C standard, in the absence of a regular definition in the same translation unit (source file being compiled, including all included files), it serves as a definition.

When a definition is supplied in one translation unit and a tentative definition of the same identifier is supplied in another translation unit, the C standard does not define the behavior, but Unix tools commonly allow the tentative definitions to be coalesced, allowing the link to complete.

Comment: This behaviour has changed in gcc-10: https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/porting_to.html